# How can I merge cells of Excel package worksheet in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, worksheet

I just want to merge number of cells in one column using worksheet of `ExcelPackage`; There is the way that I create my worksheet:

```
        var excelFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
        var package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile);
        var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
```

So How can I merge cells in this worksheet?
I will be thankful for any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Place data in cells
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Cell A1";
// Or [row, column] notation:
worksheet.Cells[2,1].Value = "Cell A2";

// Merge cells
worksheet.Cells["A1:B1"].Merge = true;
// Or [row, column] notation:
worksheet.Cells[FromRow, FromColumn, ToRow, ToColumn].Merge = true;
```